# $f(z)=\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$, $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{1,-1\}$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{x\in \mathbb{R}: |x|>1 \}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I'm trying to prove that $f(z)=\log(\frac{1+z}{1-z})$,  $z \in \mathbb{C} \setminus \{1,-1\}$  is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C}\setminus \{x\in \mathbb{R}: |x|>1 \}$

to test this my idea is to derive the logarithm function  and I get that $f'(z)=\frac{\frac{2}{(1-z)^{2}}}{\frac{1+z}{1-z}}=\frac{2(1-z)}{(1-z)^2(1+z)}$ and hence $z\not=1$ and $z\not=-1$ but 
and this leads me to think if this domain where the problem says that the function is holomorphic is not correct, on the other hand I think that an analysis of this can also be done by expanding to taylor series.

PD:I saw this problem in a complex analysis book from the University of Granada.

Answer (score 1):

Let's consider the simpler example
$$f(z)=\log(z)$$
Your reasoning also applies here, right?
$$f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$
and so we would claim that $f$ is holomorphic in $\mathbb{C} \setminus 0$.

This conclusion is, however, not correct. Let's think carefully about what it means to define a function such as the above logarithm. It means that $f(z)$ is such that $e^{f(z)}=z$. But this by itself has many possible solutions. In fact, we get
$$f(z)=\log(|z|)+i\arg(z)$$
which is a multi-valued function, since the [argument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Argument_(complex_analysis)) is basically the angle with respect to the positive real axis and has many possible values (you can always add or subtract $2\pi$). So what do we do? We pick one of these.

If we force $\arg(z)$ to take values in, say, $]-\pi,\pi]$, it becomes, along with the above logarithm, single-valued. This is what is called choosing a branch of these functions (see [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_branch) and [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value)).

Both become discontinuous, however, at the negative real axis (called the [branch cut](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Branch_point#Branch_cuts)). So, if you consider these branch cuts, you can't say that the function is holomorphic in the negative real axis. However, the derivative does not actually care about which branch you're working on, since changing the branch just adds a constant. So, at a given point, you can always pick a branch that makes the function continuous at that point and take the derivative, which will be independent of said choice. So writting
$$f'(z)=\frac{1}{z}$$
actually makes sense but its $\textbf{not}$ meant to claim that the function with the branch cut is holomorphic everywhere except at the origin.

In your case, the set of holomorphicity you were given just comes from the fact that you have two branch cuts, one for $x>1$, and one for $x<-1$.

Answer (score 0):

It is not really correct to say $\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)$ is holomorphic there: for one thing, you haven't specified which branch of the logarithm you are talking about.
Also you don't want $+1$ or $-1$ to be in the domain, and $\mathbb C \backslash \{z \in \mathbb R: |z| > 1\}$ would include those.
What is true is that there is a branch of the logarithm of $(1+z)/(1-z)$ that is holomorphic in $U = \mathbb C \backslash \{z \in \mathbb R: |z| \ge 1\}$.    One way to see this is to note that $U$ is
simply connected and consider the antiderivative of $2/(1-z^2)$ with value $0$ at $z=0$.